# why output sometimes fails

Tags: c++

I am practicing programing on codechef, there is a exercise "smart factorial",

The question is:

Input
An integer t, 1<=t<=100, denoting the number of testcases, followed by t lines, each containing a single integer n, 1<=n<=100.

Output

For each integer n given at input, display a line with the value of n!
Example

Sample input:

```
4
1
2
5
3
```

Sample output:

```
1
2
120
6
```

I wrote my fact.cpp, but its output is weird. Sometimes it's correct, but sometimes its output is like this:

```
6
100
150485922355943662067262689687459530715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000(suppose it's right)
(FOLLOWING IS NOT MY INPUT,IT'S OUTPUT)
1
1
1
1
1
$
```

What's the problem, I can't figure it out.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void mult(vector<int>& a, int n); // vector = a*n
int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    int numOfLine;
    cin>> numOfLine;

    while(numOfLine)
    {
        int num; //Sometimes fails here!!!! Why??????
        cin >> num;
        vector<int> res;
        res.push_back(1);

        for(int i=0;i<num;++i)
        {
            mult(res,i+1);
        }

        int n = res.size();

        for(;n>0;n--)
        {
            cout << res[n-1];
        }

        cout << endl;
        numOfLine--;
    }
}

void mult(vector<int>& a, int n)
{
    int s = a.size();
    int j;  //accumulator
    a.push_back(0); //n<=100
    a.push_back(0);

    for(int i=0;i<s;++i) //first mult every digit
    {
        a[i] = a[i]*n;
    }

    //second shift left
    for(int i=0;i<s;++i)
    {
        int tmp = a[i];
        j = i;

        while(tmp)
        {
            if(j==i)
            {
                a[j++] = tmp%10;
                tmp /= 10;
            }
            else
            {
                a[j++] += tmp%10;
                tmp /= 10;
            }
        }
    }

    //pop_back beginning zero
    int t = s+1;
    while(!a[t])
    {
        a.pop_back();
        t--;
    }
}
```

Comment: TLDR but you should _always_ initialize your variables, and you shouldn't do such overcomplicated things with your vectors and loops.

Comment: It would help, if you format your code "reasonable" :-)

Comment: I would start with looking at the case that gave output 100, since it's obviously wrong and not terribly tedious to debug.

Comment: Take a closer look at `mult`. You are probably missing some 'carry management'. I ran your code and got wrong response for 99! and 100!. At MINGW I didn not get bad formatted output. Generate big factorialas [here](http://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/discretemathematics/factorials.php).

Answer (score -1):

Here you go:

```
#include <iostream>

int factorial(int num){
    if(num==1) return num;
    return num*factorial(num-1);
}

int main(){
    int lines;
    std::cin >> lines;
    for(int i=0; i<lines; i++){
        int n;
        std::cin >> n;
        std::cout << factorial(n) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: ohh just noticed that the numbers given can be up to a 100, the above won't work with numbers greater than about 15

Comment: The problem stays that the solution should take n==100, as @Dima Maligin pointed out.